# Add GADBannerView Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I created a class as AdMobViewController and I use to add banner this class. Banner create but other objects in view don't scroll up. How I do programmatically scroll up all objects in view.

My AdMobViewController class and method:

```
+ (void)createBanner:(UIViewController *)sender
{
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testing = YES;
    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];

    GADBannerView *bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
    bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-123456";
    bannerView.rootViewController = (id)self;
    bannerView.delegate = (id<GADBannerViewDelegate>)self;
    bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 518, 320, 50);

    [bannerView loadRequest:request];

    [sender.view addSubview:bannerView];
}
```

And I use for creating banner:

```
[AdMobViewController createBanner:self];
```

Comment: what is the difference between DFPBannerView and GADBannerView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think you have multiple things to consider:

1. `[sender.view addSubview:bannerView]` does not move other views,
   instead you are placing the banner view directly on top of the view
   hierarchy.
2. Ads are loaded asynchronously, so you should implement the delegate
   methods of `GADBannerView` for showing and hiding the ad view.
3. If you really want to move other views around you should use some
   kind of container view to include all other content except your
   banner. If you receive an ad you can easily move the container view
   (or shrink it) and display your banner view on some location in your
   main view.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you to reply. How can I programmatically transfer objects other programmatically created view?

Comment: Can you be more specific on your question?

Comment: what is the difference between DFPBannerView and GADBannerView?

Answer (score 7):

Working sample copy is here:

For using: [AdMobViewController createBanner:self];

```
#import "AdMobViewController.h"
#import "GADBannerView.h"

@interface AdMobViewController ()

@end

@implementation AdMobViewController

static GADBannerView *bannerView;
static UIView *senderView;
static UIView *containerView;
static UIView *bannerContainerView;
static float bannerHeight;

+ (void)createBanner:(UIViewController *)sender
{
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        bannerHeight = 50;
    }
    else
    {
        bannerHeight = 90;
    }

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];

    bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
    bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx";
    bannerView.rootViewController = (id)self;
    bannerView.delegate = (id<GADBannerViewDelegate>)self;

    senderView = sender.view;

    bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, senderView.frame.size.width, bannerHeight);

    [bannerView loadRequest:request];

    containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:senderView.frame];

    bannerContainerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, senderView.frame.size.height, senderView.frame.size.width, bannerHeight)];

    for (id object in sender.view.subviews) {

        [object removeFromSuperview];
        [containerView addSubview:object];

    }

    [senderView addSubview:containerView];
    [senderView addSubview:bannerContainerView];
}

+ (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)view
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

        containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, senderView.frame.size.width, senderView.frame.size.height - bannerHeight);
        bannerContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, senderView.frame.size.height - bannerHeight, senderView.frame.size.width, bannerHeight);
        [bannerContainerView addSubview:bannerView];

    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: what is the difference between DFPBannerView and GADBannerView?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the delegate callback `adViewDidReceiveAd:`, check the size of the ad and move your views accordingly

Comment: what is the difference between DFPBannerView and GADBannerView? `- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(DFPBannerView *)bannerView;` and `- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView;` I saw them both.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
GADBannerView *gv=[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
[self.view addSubview:gv];

gv.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx";
gv.rootViewController = self;
gv.delegate=(id<GADBannerViewDelegate>)self;
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
// Enable test ads on simulators.
request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];
[gv loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an aside, because my problem looked similar, but was not.

**App ID** is **NOT** the same as **Ad Unit ID**.

And, stupidly, they BOTH start with **ca-app-pub-** and a lot of numbers. I was using the App ID which I can *guarantee* 100% does NOT work.

Yes, I feel pretty silly, but the folks at Google should have made them dissimilar.

However, if you use the Ad Unit ID, surprisingly, everything works. :)