# App crash at [UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] in viewdidload method

Tags: swift, swift2

Xcode organizer crash section only showing this error. Not providing actual reason of crash.

> MyApp
>
> 0x1000ab038 0x100054000 + 356408
>
> UIKit                           [UIViewController loadViewIfRequired]
>   + 360
>
> UIKit                           [UINavigationController _layoutViewController:]
>
> UIKit                           [UINavigationController
>   _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:]
>
> UIKit                           [UINavigationController
>   _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:]

on my app’s initial view controller my code is 
create bannerView just after  super.viewDidLoad() method call

```
override func viewDidLoad() { 

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // create the banner
    bannerView = GADBannerView(frame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50))
    bannerView.adUnitID = adMobUnitID
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.hidden = true
    bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait
    let request = GADRequest()

    bannerView.loadRequest(request)
    self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: What does the rest of the stack look like?  Which view controllers are involved?

Comment: Can you post some code involved?

Comment: Check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760071/add-gadbannerview-programmatically